# Loopback related model property problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, loopbackjs

I have a `user` model (extending from built in `User`) and a `UserDetail` model which are related:

`user` relations:

```
    "relations": {
        "userDetails": {
            "type": "hasOne",
            "model": "UserDetail",
            "foreignKey": "userDetailUserId"
        },
```

If I run the code below in node, I can see the userDetails property on the returned object, but cannot access it directly.

```
var User = app.models.user;
User.findOne({
      include: 'userDetails',
      where: {id: userId}
},function(err,user){
  console.log('log');
  console.log(user);
  console.log(user.userDetails);
  console.log(user.userDetailFirstName);
  console.log(user.userDetails.userDetailFirstName);
})
```

The log is as follows:

```
log

{ my user details ....
id: 100,
userDetails:
   { userDetailId: 13,
   userDetailUserId: 100,
   userDetailFirstName: 'Stephen',
   userDetailLastName: 'Knox',} }
{ [Function]
   getAsync: [Function],
   create: [Function],
   build: [Function],
   update: [Function],
   destroy: [Function],
   _targetClass: 'UserDetail' }

undefined
undefined
```

Rather than giving me the userDetails object, which I can see, I get the [`hasOne` methods](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Accessing+related+models). This seems odd behaviour but I can't find anything wrong with the model or relationship definition.

Can anyone help?

Comment: @stev-k : Tried all methods but still not working for me. :( Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in order to access a related model, you need to call user.userDetails().

Or, you can call user.toJSON() and this will give you a plain JS object

Comment: Tried all methods but still not working for me. :( Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was pulling my hair trying to understand why am I not getting a related object. Experimenting with `.toJSON()` fixed it.